# Python Selenium Scraping missing image from url

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Hello all my task is to scrap source urls from offer link [like this one](http://www.kmart.com/joe-boxer-men-s-pajama-shirt-pants-plaid/p-046VA92629712P).

But when I try to get the elements like this (Note that I make 2 requests of the url to get the cookies, because the first time is redirecting me to the main page):

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\selenium-drivers\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("http://www.kmart.com/joe-boxer-men-s-pajama-shirt-pants-plaid/p-046VA92629712P")
driver.get("http://www.kmart.com/joe-boxer-men-s-pajama-shirt-pants-plaid/p-046VA92629712P")
img_element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("main-image")
```

No elements are found and when i try to search them in the source code in the browser with Ctrl+U they are missing. Why is this happening? Is anyone who can tell me how to get these images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to tell selenium to be patient and [wait for element's *visibility*](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# driver definition here

driver.get("http://www.kmart.com/joe-boxer-men-s-pajama-shirt-pants-plaid/p-046VA92629712P")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# get the main image element
img_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'main-image')))
print(img_element.get_attribute("alt"))

driver.close()
```

For the demonstration purposes, it prints the `alt` attribute of the image, which is:

```
Joe Boxer Men's Pajama Shirt & Pants - Plaid
```

Comment: Oh my god you are my savior! Thank you i didn't know that there is function for waiting the element. Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just find by xpath and then get image url

```
>>> driver.get('http://www.kmart.com/joe-boxer-men-s-pajama-shirt-pants-plaid/p-046VA92629712P')
>>> s = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="overview"]/div[1]/img')
>>> s.get_attribute('src') 
'http://c.shld.net/rpx/i/s/i/spin/-122/prod_2253990712?hei=624&wid=624&op_sharpen=1'
```